# Output in another file

Tags: c, file, io

```
    int i, largest = 0, temp, temp2, temp3;






            temp1 = products[n-1].name;

            strcpy(products[n-1].name,products[largest].name);

            strcpy(products[largest].name, temp1);
```

These are the points were the issue was and the issue has now been fixed, thanks for the help!

Comment: `temp`, `temp2`, and `temp3` are all `int` variables, but you assign `double` values to them, and then re-assign then back to `double` values. You should make these ones `double`. The `i` and `largest` variables can remain as `int`.

Comment: You haven't described clearly what your program is supposed to do. Do you think "grape number number lowest number" makes much sense to someone who does not know what the program is supposed to be doing? And you haven't provided the input.

Comment: Please do not edit the question so as to invalidate the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that the `temp`, `temp2`, and `temp3` are `int`, but you are assigning `double` values to them, and then re-assigning these values back to `double` variables. You should make these `double`.

You might want to consider using [`qsort()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html) to sort these objects.

```
#include <stdlib.h> // for qsort

int compare_products(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const struct product *product1 = p1;
    const struct product *product2 = p2;

    // swap product1 and product2 around to reverse sort order
    return (int)(product1->sale_volume - product2->sale_volume);
}

int main()
{
     // ...

     qsort(products, line_amount, sizeof(struct product), compare_products);

     for(i = 0; i < line_amount; i++){
         fprintf(pFile, "%s \t  %lf \t %lf \t %lf\n", products[i].name, products[i].unit_price, products[i].tot_pounds_sold, products[i].sale_volume);
     }

     // ...    
}
```

Since you must use the `selection_sort` function, it can be made quite a bit simpler due to `struct` objects being assignable.

```
void selection_sort(struct product products[], int n)
{
    int i, largest = 0;

    if (n == 1) {
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (products[i].sale_volume > products[largest].sale_volume) {
            largest = i;
        }
    }

    struct product temp = products[n - 1];
    products[n - 1] = products[largest];
    products[largest] = temp;

    selection_sort(products, n - 1);
}
```

Comment: @YellowBird: Add the `compare_products` function to your source code, and in your main function, instead of calling your `selection_sort` function, call the `qsort` function like I have in my answer. Then your `products` array will be sorted for you. Your `selection_sort` function won't be needed (nor will the use of `strcpy` etc). Don't forget to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @YellowBird: You need to make these requirements clear so people don't waste their time with unusable answers. I will update my answer for you.

Comment: @YellowBird: Oops I changed the loop to start at 1 because I was trying to do the selection sort forwards rather than backwards. The `struct product temp` is so that I can copy an entire `struct product` into it, rather than maintaining temporary variables and copying the individual members of `struct product` manually. I'm not sure what you mean about the name, I'm not referring to any specific field of `struct product` purposefully, because it is unnecessary.

Comment: For that, you could perhaps loop over all of the products, and use `strcmp(products[i].name, user_input)` where `user_input` is a string provided by the user. If `strcmp()` returns 0, it means the strings are identical. Once you have a match, you can just use `printf` to print out all the information about the product.